# Branch.io closure gets called whenever accessing photos, purchases, localization etc

Tags: ios, plist, branch.io

so my problem is that when user first time allows app to enter library, making a inapppurchase, or localization initSession's closure from addDelegate is being trigged, and causing opening vc again. Every accessing behaves the same, they're not connected with branch in any way, and also their superview vc’s don’t even import branch. So I think the problem might be inside my info.plist but everything seems to be correct, and don’t know whats wrong. Anyone help. Thanks

[plist printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azf2A.png)

```
var window: UIWindow?
func ...didFinishLaunchingWithOptions... {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = firstVC()

let branch = Branch.getInstance()
branch?.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
if error == nil && params?["+clicked_branch_link"] != nil && params?["postKey"] != nil{
self.window?.rootViewController = MainVC()
}else{
self.window.rootViewController = LoginVC()
}
})
}
```

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: I'm afraid your question is very difficult to understand. Could you edit to include a specific step-by-step explanation of exactly what you see, or post a video showing the issue?

Comment: @AlexBauer sorry for late reply but was busy. Ok so i'll give you a stepbystep explanation since i'd rather not share app screens. So, lets say i'm launching my app, when main(first) view controller is loaded it shows alert with permission to access app localization service, when i press "Allow" callback from 'branch?.initSession(launchingOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in ...}' is being called, and because inside this handler i got my rootviewcontroller for app it's called again. This happens only within your initSession handler, not inside didFinishLaunchi

Comment: Your comment got cut off. Could you please _edit_ your original question with step-by-step info on the issue? Alternatively, feel free to get in touch with the Branch [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)

Answer (score 0):

The Branch init callback will be triggered whenever the app becomes active. For a cold start, this is triggered by the init call in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. For a warm start, this is triggered by the Branch code you add in continueUserActivity or (rarely now) openURL. This is made possible by the SDK maintaining a pointer to the init callback, and the SDK will also register an "open" or "install" event, as appropriate.

Whenever the app is terminated or backgrounded, the Branch SDK will register a "close" event and clear all session data.

From your description, it sounds like your app gets backgrounded when you prompt the user to grant various permissions to the app. When this happens, the SDK is closing the session and clearing the session parameters. When the app resumes, it is no longer a referred session and therefore there are no link parameters available.

There are two basic approaches to resolving this type of issue:

1. Store the Branch link parameters that you are interested in using local storage so that they can be retrieved when the app becomes active the second time
2. Modify the app design so that it no longer produces these pop-up permissions prompts

Comment: thank you for your answer but figured it out, the solution was to change observers within branch code from becameActive and willResign to didEnterBakground and willEnterForeground

Comment: Awesome! It would be great if you could post that as the official answer for this question.